# Using FPAT to split a CSV file and replace any embedded commas with a space " "

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a text file with a sample record that looks like this...

`Tampa,Orlando,"Jacksonville,FL",Miami,"Tallahassee,FL"`

I need to replace the embedded commas in position 3 and 5 with a space " "

Here is the awk code I have in a bash script...

```
AWK_script="BEGIN {
   OFS=\",\"
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
   {
      if ( \$i==3 || \$i==5 )
      {
         gsub(\",\",\" \",\$i)
      }
   }
   print \$0
}
"

echo 'Tampa,Orlando,"Jacksonville,FL",Miami,"Tallahassee,FL"' | awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' "${AWK_script}"
```

I'm unable to get the gsub to substitute the embedded commas to a space " ". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Eliminate a whole class of errors and resist the temptation to  have programming code in env variables. Put code in a file, it will simplify your problem. BUT, excellent [mcve]! Good luck.

Comment: If you think this is easier to read, here is the command line version of my original code...

`$ echo 'Tampa,Orlando,"Jacksonville,FL",Miami,"Tallahassee,FL"' | awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' 'BEGIN { OFS="," } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ( $i==3 || $i==5 ) { gsub(","," ",$i) } } print $0 }'

Tampa,Orlando,"Jacksonville,FL",Miami,"Tallahassee,FL"`

Comment: `$i` is the **contents** of field number `i`. You want `if (i == 3 || i == 5)`

Comment: @glennjackman OMG!!! Something so simple. Just needed another set of eyes. That was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're making things much harder for yourself by using double quotes around the awk script and storing it in a string. Strings are for storing text, functions are for storing code. Every string or script should be enclosed in single quotes unless you **need** double quotes and then use those unless you **need** no quotes. Use single quotes around it and store it in a function instead. Among other things, if you do that you can get rid of all those backslashes before the double quotes and `$`s inside the awk script.

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

deComma() {
    awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS=',' '
        {
           for (i=3; i<=5; i+=2) {
               gsub(/,/," ",$i)
           }
           print
        }
    ' "${@:--}"
}

echo 'Tampa,Orlando,"Jacksonville,FL",Miami,"Tallahassee,FL"' | deComma
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Tampa,Orlando,"Jacksonville FL",Miami,"Tallahassee FL"
```

See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information on parsing CSVs with awk, including why I changed your `FPAT` setting.